# Ruby: create a String from bytes

Tags: ruby, string, byte

I would like to build a string from a byte value.

I currently use:

```
str = " "
str[0] = byte
```

This seems to work fine but I find it ugly and not very scalable to strings longer than 1 character.

Any idea?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is a much simpler approach than any of the above: [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002245):

```
>> [65,66,67,68,69].pack('c*')
=>  "ABCDE"
```

I believe pack is implemented in c in matz ruby, so it also will be considerably faster with very large arrays.

Also, pack can correctly handle UTF-8 using the 'U*' template.

Comment: This answer describes the correct way to do it. But remember to set the encoding correctly in Ruby 1.9 as the answer by grosser points out!

Comment: You got 'lucky' with the lowercase `c*`. You really want `C*`. See:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html `c` is for "8-bit signed (signed char)", `C` is for "8-bit unsigned (unsigned char)"

Comment: Pack can NOT correctly handle UTF-8 using the "U*" template. This is incorrect. "U*" packs an array of Unicode codepoints, not UTF8 bytes.

Comment: @DavidJames can you demonstrate a case where C* works and c* doesn't? All unicode has a 1 in GSB and is therefore "signed", right? But this works fine: 
    irb(main):001:0> puts ["11010111", "10101010"].map{|x|x.to_i(2)}.pack('c*') # (gives the string "ת")

Comment: @A.Wilson see my example in the comments for http://stackoverflow.com/a/4701955/109618

Comment: I did see that, I was wondering specifically if it ever made a difference with pack (rather than unpack). This is still important to avoid confusion, I recognize, I'm just wondering if that's the only reason for the caveat

Answer (score 21):

for 1.9 you need:

```
[195,164].pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Comment: I recommend using `C*` because you want unsigned integers. `c*` is for signed integers. Note that: `"ä".unpack('c*')` == `[-61, -92]`. What you want is: `"ä".unpack('C*')` == `[195, 164]`

Answer (score 10):

can't remember if there is a single function that does that:

```
>> a = [65,66,67]
=> [65, 66, 67]
>> a.map {|x| x.chr}.join
=> "ABC"
```

Comment: Nice, did not know about the chr method

Comment: @VincentRobert How can you / can you do this example in that style? `[195,164].pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8')`

Comment: Got it: `[195,164].map { |x| x.chr }.join.force_encoding('UTF-8')`

Comment: More compact: `a.map(&:chr).join`

Answer (score 4):

If bytes is an array of Fixnum's you could try this:

```
bytes.map {|num| num.chr}.join
```

or this:

```
s = ''
bytes.each {|i| s << i}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the OP's question, but if you have just a single byte (not in an array) and want to make a string out of it, use `chr`

```
c = 65
=> 65
c.chr
=> "A"
c.chr.class
=> String
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution does not work well as of today (2024), it was probably fine in 2009. Nowadays [UTF-8 is the de facto Internet encoding standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) so we will encode bytes to it. What I found works is a combination of previous good suggestions, I resume the proposed solution in a new answer for ease of future readers reference. bye

```
# BAD, previously suggested, today bytes do not encode only ASCII 
irb> "a α b β".bytes.pack("c*")  
 => "a \xCE\xB1 b \xCE\xB2" 

# BAD, previously suggested, pack("U*") works well only if 
# the array of Int represent UTF-8 integers, larger than bytes. 
# try  "a α b β".unpack("U*").pack("U*").
irb> "a α b β".bytes.pack("U*")  
 => "a Î± b Î²"

# OK, proposed solution in 2024
irb> "a α b β".bytes.pack("C*").force_encoding("UTF-8") 
 => "a α b β"
```